# Firebase authentication returning 400 with angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have enabled authentication via Google in the console:
[image]

login code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user = {};
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        // user logged in
        this.user = user;
      }
      else {
        // user not logged in
        this.user = {};
      }
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The call to `this.af.auth.login()` produces the error below.

```
www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyDyJQVTQI-a-eW2iM70RXAcVHKDb0NP1Ek:1 POST 

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyDyJQVTQI-a-eW2iM70RXAcVHKDb0NP1Ek 400 ()
core.es5.js:1084ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:712) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:683) [angular]
    at polyfills.bundle.js:3492:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) [<root>]
```

A Google search reveals that this was a problem when the Firebase SDK was < 3. I am using the most recent version of angularfire2 so this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override login configuration in angularFire2, both method and provider should be set. Try to login like:

```
import { AuthMethods, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';

  login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      method: AuthMethods.Redirect,
      provider: AuthProviders.Google
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched Google and hung out in the angularfire2 Gitter and couldn't find this anywhere.